# Windows Command Line : START Command Switch /I meaning?

Tags: windows, command-line, switch-statement

From ss64.com: 
/I         : Ignore any changes to the current environment.

What does that mean?  If you could give examples of usage and what it effects or doesn't effect, that would be great (none provided on website and have google searched with no luck).

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers! They are all right but I had to pick one that was solid and to the point (with minimal reading =P).  I gave everyone UPs however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you modified the current environment by defining a variable;

```
set foo=bar
start app.exe
```

App.exe would see `%foo%` as being `"bar"`

```
set foo=bar
start /i app.exe
```

App.exe would see `%foo%` as being undefined.

Comment: So then you're actually creating a NEW environment altogether ignoring any rules placed before the START command?

Comment: yeah... To add to it, you would change the default environment. By that, I mean you would create system variables.

Answer (score 3):

`/I` means that The new environment will be the original environment passed to the cmd.exe and not the current environment. Any changes made to the environment variables, paths, will not reflect in the current START instance.

It Passes the Cmd.exe startup environment to the new Command Prompt window, and nothing else.

See [this](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm)

Comment: all those which set for a cmd window by default, are set... Ones set by the user temporarily are not.

Answer (score 1):

From running `start /?` on my W7 box:

> The new environment will be the
>   original environment passed to the
>   cmd.exe and not the current
>   environment.

So the environment variables given are the ones given to the instances of `cmd` that `start` is invoked from, rather than the current environment stored on the system.

Example:

```
> set lol=1
> echo %lol%
1
> cmd
> echo %lol%
1
```

Now if I were to invoke a batch file which ran `echo %lol%`, but using the `/I` switch for start - `%lol` would not be defined, because I have changed the original environment settings passed to my original `cmd.exe`.

Why would you use it? Well say you needed to change %PATH% temporarily but then invoke a script that perhaps relied on the original version. `start /I` would be ideal here because no matter what you set it to, the environment passed to the `cmd` started by `start` will be whatever it was before you started your first instance of `cmd`.